# Multiple assignment

Tags: tcl

I would like to do the following python-like operation:

```
set var [list 1 2 3]
set {x y z} $var
puts "$x $y $z"
```

where the first element in var is assigned to x, and so on.
The above doesn't work as it creates a variable named `x y z`.

Is there a way to do this?  My real case is I want to return multiple values from a function and assign each value to a different variable.  In the worst case, I can return a dict with recognizable names, but would prefer this approach.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do something like this if you receive a list containing the results you need:

```
proc someFunction {} {
    return [list valA valB valC]
}

lassign [someFunction] x y z
puts "First: $x, second: $y, third $z"
# => First: valA, second: valB, third: valC
```

[`lassign`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/lassign.htm) works on Tcl 8.5 and later versions.

---

In your particular example:

```
set var [list 1 2 3]
lassign $var x y z
puts "$x $y $z"
```

Answer (score 2):

If you prefer the Python-like syntax, it's quite easy to make a command to allow it:

```
proc mset {names values} {
    uplevel 1 lassign [list $values] $names
}
```

Usage:

```
set var [list 1 2 3]
mset {x y z} $var
puts "$x $y $z"
```

The `mset` (*multiset*) command takes as arguments one list of names and one list of values (preferably of the same length, but it can deal with lists of differing lengths too). It evaluates the `lassign` command in the caller's stack level. The `uplevel` command concatenates the words of the invocation of `lassign` together as if `concat` had been called on them, which means that the invocation `lassign {1 2 3} {x y z}` will be evaluated as `lassign 1 2 3 x y z`. By adding one more nested list around the first argument (`lassign {{1 2 3}} {x y z}`) we get the invocation `lassign {1 2 3} x y z` instead.

Documentation: [concat](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/concat.htm), [lassign](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lassign.htm), [list](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/list.htm), [proc](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/proc.htm), [puts](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/puts.htm), [set](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/set.htm), [uplevel](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/uplevel.htm)